# usage of ternary operators in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to learn things.

Is it posible to avoid the use of temporary variables ?

```
<?php

    function get_name()
    {
        // assume that this function return 3 
        // values on different conditions "name0" "name1" or "name2";
    }

    $result =  ( get_name() == "name0" || get_name() == "name1") ? "Primary" : "Secondary" ;
    echo $result;

?>
```

on the above i am calling the `get_name()` function two times , which means two calls on the same function.

Is it possible to achieve the same with just one call without saving it into a temporary variable?

What is the commonly used practices ?

**Update : I edited the question to be more specific.Almost all answers are satisfactory,Hope that this update will help for new readers.**

Comment: [`$result = in_array(get_value(), array(0, NULL), true) ? 'Zero' : 'One';`](http://us.php.net/in_array). Though the requirement "without saving it into temporary variable" is unusual - there's nothing wrong with them...

Comment: In my opinion, using a temporary variable with a meaningful name, makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do that:

```
$result =  in_array(get_value(), array(0, NULL), true) ? "Zero" : "One" ;
```

Documentation: [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

Comment: could you please explain little-bit ?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? This calls the function [`in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = false)`](http://us.php.net/in_array), which checks if the `$needle` is in the second argument `$haystack, using either strict or loose comparison. Depending on your actual use-case and return values, you might need to use the strict comparison option.

Comment: `$strict` needs to be set to `true`, otherwise a return value of `false` or `"0"` will cause `in_array()` to return `true`.

Comment: May be a noob Question , but i have to ask to learn , i dont know how `in_array` works , i mean its source , is there any chance that php will call this function more times ? because i got a tip that `Try to use functions outside loops. Otherwise the function may get called each time. `

Comment: I added a link to the documentation for in_array. The function is called only once in my code.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
$result = get_value() ? "One" : "Zero";
```

This causes `get_value()` to be typecast to a boolean.  `null` and `0` become `false`, and `1` becomes `true`.

Comment: I am sorry , but that was just an example . May be i presented it wrong,the function returns different values on different conditions.

Comment: Ah, too bad.  Then I would recommend Jocelyn's `in_array` solution.

Comment: This looks very nifty, but it can also lead to misunderstandings if somebody else has to read this code (you need additional knowledge about `get_value()` to understand it).

Comment: Really sorry for the inconvenience , i just meant that  `get_value()` returns different values ...

Comment: No problem!  And back to the boolean typecasting -- it's good a have a really thorough understanding of [how php converts to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) any time you're using ternary operators like this.

Comment: Actuary i was about to hit a `four` through the question , but its now gone to `six` .:)

Answer (score 1):

The function is called two times because the `===` operator is used, and it will output Zero only if the return value is exactly `0` or `null`, but not if it's false or empty string.

A common approach is

```
$result =  ( get_value() ) ? "Zero" : "One" ;
```

which will output Zero for `false` and empty string as well.

If you need the strict check, and assuming that get_value() is an expensive function, you can do:

```
$result =  ( in_array(get_value(), array(0, null), true ) ? "Zero" : "One" ;
```

There are again 2 function calls, but one is to the `in_array` function.

it would be more readable if you just save the result in temporary variable.

Even better, do not return mixed result from the get_value() function

Comment: I am sorry , but that was just an example . May be i presented it wrong,the function returns different values on different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<? echo (get_value())?"One":"Zero";?>
```

Comment: I am sorry , but that was just an example . May be i presented it wrong,the function returns different values on different conditions.